# Can I use Coq to formalise the proofs from Terence Tao's Real Analysis textbook?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, theorem-provers

I'm working through Terence Tao's Real Analysis textbooks which start from Peano's axioms and build up from there and I was wondering can I use [Coq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq) to formalise and verify my proofs but without having to learn the existing libraries? I would like to start from scratch: enter the same axioms and then to refer only to them and to the previously proven statements in my proofs. The book uses set-theoretic framework.

Comment: that would be quite obscene in my opinion